# Can we store a value of a set in a variable? Like we can store a value of an array in a variable

Tags: c++, stl

I have tried to store a value of a set into a variable. I try this:

```
int a[1000],c[1000],ara[10000],t,n,i,j;
cin>>n;
set<int>st;
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    cin>>a[i];
    st.insert(a[i]);
}
int p = st.size();
int m;
for(i=0;i<p;i++)
    m = st[i];
```

> error: no match for 'operator[]' (operand types are 'std::set<int>' and 'int')

Comment: Please show us what `st` is.

Comment: I have edited the sample  code sorry for mistake.

Comment: [`std::set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) has no `operator[]`. What would you expect it would return if it did have such an operator? Are you thinking of a [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) ?? Or are you jus interested in iterating the set (in which case, an *iterator* would be useful).

Comment: Are you sure that's the error you are getting? What about: st1 is not defined?

Comment: it show me the same thing... the set is okay with st. but getting the same error

Answer (score 2):

`std::set` does not have an `operator[]`, like an array does. You are trying to iterate through the values stored in the `set`. You do that using **iterators**, eg:

```
int n, j;
cin >> n;
set<int> st;
for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    cin >> j;
    st.insert(j);
}
for(set<int>::iterator iter = st.begin(); iter != st.end(); ++iter)
{
    int m = *iter;
    // use m as needed...
}
/* simpler:
for(int m : st)
{
    // use m as needed...
}
*/
```

Comment: Thanks! a lot. Now i get the the solutions!

Answer (score 1):

A `std::set` does not support the concept of accessing elements via an index or key. It behaves more like a mathmatical set. That's why it does not overload `operator[]` and you can't access it's elements like that of an array, vector or map.

You can, however, iterate through the elements of a `std::set` using iterators:

```
for(auto it = st.begin(), end = st.end(); it != end; ++it) {
    m = *it;
}
```

Or let the compiler do all the nasty stuff with a range-based for:

```
for(int item : st) {
    m = item;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you encounter such compiler errors, indicating you are using wrong a `stl` container, algorithm, ..., you can easily look it up at cppreference.com. Here is an example for [set](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set). You will see that there is no `operator[]` for `std::set`, hence the compiler error. Also, in your first `for` looop, you use `st1` instead of `st`.

You seem to want to iterate over the `std::set`. You can do this in several ways, one is:

```
std::set<int> mySet;
/* ... */
for (const auto& element : mySet)
{ /* ... */ }
```

Note though that in your second loop, you'll just store the biggest `int` of the `std::set` in the variable `m`.

You probably confused a `std::set` with a [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map), which does have an `operator[]`.

Comment: Thanks! I get it and i slove the problem.